# Do non-concurrent nsoperations execute in a serial fashion?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, parallel-processing, nsoperation

From: [Apple docs on managing concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html):

> **NsOperation**
>
> Write a custom subclass and override one method: main. The main method gets called to perform the operation when the NSOperationQueue schedules it to run. NSOperation classes written in this way are known as non-concurrent operations, because the developer is not responsible for spawning threads—multi-threading is all handled by the super class. (Don’t be confused by the terminology: just because an operation is non-concurrent, does not mean it cannot be executed concurrently, it simply means that you don't have to handle the concurrency yourself.)

I think overriding main is the easiest way to use `NSOperation`, but the apple site says its non-concurrent does it mean that the nsoperations in the nsoperation queue(when only overriding main) would execute serially?

I don't want to execute my operations serially, but I want to get my operations parallel with as minimum effort as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not *necessarily* be run serially. Just as the paragraph you quoted noted, it "does not mean it cannot be executed concurrently".

So what does determine if they can run in parallel? The `NSOperationQueue` and any dependencies you set up between the ops. A little later in that same document, the section entitled "Running Operations" explains:

- you can specify (limit) the number of threads the queue will spawn, and
- "NSOperationQueue will automatically determine how many threads it should spawn."

And in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html) it elaborates:

> In most cases, operations are executed shortly after being added to a queue, but the operation queue may delay execution of queued operations for any of several reasons. Specifically, execution may be delayed if queued operations are dependent on other operations that have not yet completed. Execution may also be delayed if the operation queue itself is suspended or is already executing its maximum number of concurrent operations.

What you do give up by using non-concurrent operations is that the operation itself isn't intended to set up new threads, etc.

Comment: does it mean that in non-concurrent ns operations, if i dont add any dependencies and add all the operations to the nsoperation queue,would all of them run in parallel?

Comment: Yes, again with limits on dependencies and the max limit. Added another quote from docs to support.

Comment: It means: "it depends". The decision is not yours but NSOperationQueue's - based on the state of the system (like number of available CPUs) and those others dependencies already stated it will or will not start its operations in parallel. I think it is a good solution: easy to implement, difficult to be erroneous, doesn't prevent the system to be run in parallel yet allows it to be run in serial if that's what seems to be better for NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it, but i am using "dispatch_queue_create" to create parallel processes.
Suppose if i want to do two functionalities at same time, i am using the following code. Please see if it will help you,

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("FirstOperation", 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    //Do your functionality here

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Do your UI updates here
    });
});
dispatch_release(queue);


dispatch_queue_t queue2 = dispatch_queue_create("SecondOperation", 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue2, ^{

    //Do your functionality here

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Do your UI updates here
    });
});
dispatch_release(queue2);
```